# Knockout event with bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I have a custom binding for popover:

```
init = (element: any, valueAccessor: () => any, allBindingsAccessor?: KnockoutAllBindingsAccessor, viewModel?: any, bindingContext?: KnockoutBindingContext) => {
        var $elem = $(element);
        var popover = $elem.popover({
            placement: 'auto',
            content: function () {
                return $('#' + valueAccessor() + " > div");
            },
            html: true,
            container: 'body'
        })
}


<div class="pover">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="click: function(){alert('213')}">test</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

So first time u open popover - it is shown with text and click event works fine.
Second time you open popover it is empty. B/c dom is detroyed when you hide popover.
How can i avoid this? I can't clone html, b/c click event binding will be broken...

My solution, pls tell me what can go wrong?

```
var popover = $elem.popover({
            placement: 'auto',
            content: function () {
                $("#single-popover").remove();
                $('body').append('<div id="single-popover">' + $("#popoverTemplate").html() + '</div>');
                ko.cleanNode($('#single-popover')[0]);
                ko.applyBindings(bindingContext, $('#single-popover')[0]);
                return $('#single-popover');
            },
            html: true,
            container: 'body'
        })
```

Comment: Take a look at [knockstrap](https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap) - it helps bridge the gap between the two libraries, has support for popovers.

Comment: Since the binding is invoked just once, so the html elements inside it once destroyed, are not re constructed...I too would suggest to look at knockstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would something like this work for you http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32668/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.popover = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
    var source = allBindings.get('popoverTitle');
    var sourceUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(source);
    $(element).popover({
      trigger: 'focus',
      title: sourceUnwrapped,
      placement: 'auto',
      content: function() {
        return  ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) 
      },
      html: true,
      container: 'body'
    });
  },
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor);
  }
};
```